# Creating Android Studio Plugin with UI

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am surprised I couldn't find any post on this question. I am looking to build a plugin that works as a sidebar control in Android Studio similar to how Fabric's dependency works (Illustrated below). Where can I find resources on how to get started on building this and are there any example projects on Github?

Objectives:

- Allow the developers to integrate the library as a gradle dependency
- Display a Sidebar User interface for the developers to interact with

I referred to the official [IntelliJ Docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) but I couldn't find any information on UI-based plugin development.

Questions:

> 1) Are there any development kits to build the UI?
>
> 2) Documentation on developing the plugin

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the UI? IntelliJ IDEA is a Java Swing application, so the UI is developed using Swing. If your UI can use the standard Swing components, IntelliJ IDEA provides the GUI Designer to develop the dialog forms visually, otherwise you will have to either write it by hand or use some third-party framework.

Comment: You misunderstood. By UI I meant the sidebar plugin's UI as illustrated by the Fabric example in the question. These are custom plugins developed for Android Studio @CrazyCoder

Comment: One of the examples would be the Markdown plug-in, it renders .md files in HTML and shows the result side by side with the editor. Some Markdown plug-ins utilize JavaFX for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to create is a **Tool Window** displayed right, the doc is [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/user_interface_components/tool_windows.html).

About development kits, `GUI Designer` is a tool you can use.  In fact the official example about Tool Window uses it from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/blob/master/code_samples/tool_window/src/myToolWindow/MyToolWindow.form.

But if you want to achieve similar effect like `Fabric`, [from license  page](https://fabric.io/licenses/android_plugin), it use

> - CSSBox - Copyright © 2014 Radek Burget - [Source Mirror](https://open-source-mirrored-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/CSSBox-9b22a2db7e5d92eb1ad86d26201f3db22e8a2e82.zip) - [Github](https://github.com/radkovo/CSSBox)
> - JStyleParser - Copyright © 2014 Radek Burget - [Source Mirror](https://open-source-mirrored-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/jStyleParser-78c73cc2ccd7ca4b431a8633486fd00c2fbb9f7e.zip) - [Github](https://github.com/radkovo/jStyleParser)
> - SwingBox - Copyright © 2014 Radek Burget - [Source Mirror](https://open-source-mirrored-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/SwingBox-38c381a294e5b6dbffa1e616d8bbccd175b83791.zip) - [Github](https://github.com/radkovo/SwingBox)

to render css and html effects in Java.